# How to reset Jquery animation?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a button that can be turned on/off. 
If it's turned off, I want to reset all the css values that got changed with .animate, how can I do this?

```
$('.switch1').click(function(){
    if ($('.switch1').attr('src') == 'img/off.png') {
        $('.switch1').attr('src', 'img/on.png');

        $(".img_2").fadeIn(200)
        $(".img_2").animate({"margin-left" : '-600px', "margin-top" : '-500px'}, 1500);

        $( ".img_1" ).fadeIn(400)
        $('.img_1').animate({"margin-top": '-300px'}, 3500);
    } else {
        $('.switch1').attr('src', 'img/off.png');
    }
});
```

Comment: you could save the values into a var before you change them so you can change them back to those values... or you could use css animations and just change the class to a class with the css you want... or you could use classes with jquery ui's switchClass